# How to sum values over a given date range

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, polymer, local-storage

I'm using LocalStorage to save an array of Dates and Costs.
When I'm writing `localStorage.getItem("todos");` into the console, the format will be like this:

```
"[{"due":"28/10/2017","task":"80"},{"due":"06/10/2017","task":"15"}]"
```

Where due is the Date, and TASK is the AMOUNT.

I managed to get the TOTAL of AMOUNTS by:

```
total: {
  type: String,
  value: () => {
    var values = localStorage.getItem("todos");
    if (values === undefined || values === null) {
      return "0";
    }
    var data = JSON.parse(values);
    var sum = 0;
    data.forEach(function(ele){ sum+=Number(ele.task)}); return sum;
  }
}
```

Now I'm trying to get the TOTAL of last 6 MONTHS.
I have no idea on how to approach this.
How should I be able to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During your iteration you need to add a check to make sure the sum is only including values where the due date is within your range. If you can use a library like `moment`, this would greatly simplify your logic.

```js
const data = [
  { due: '28/10/2017', task: 80 },
  { due: '06/10/2017', task: 15 },
  { due: '10/05/2000', task: 3000 }
];

const sixMonthsAgo = moment().subtract(6, 'months');

const total = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const dueDate = moment(item.due, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
  return acc + (dueDate.isAfter(sixMonthsAgo) ? item.task : 0);
}, 0);

console.log('total should equal 95: ', total);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you reply! It's working as a charm with the example you provided, but, when I'm trying to replace the dates you provided with localStorage.getItem("todos") I get an error :(

Comment: Did you parse the data from localStorage like you did in your example?

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem. Can you please tell me what should I read more about in order to understand things like these better? Thanks again!

Comment: @unkn0wnx it will just take time and experience - get familiar with the languages you use.

Comment: @chazsolo I have  asked a question about summing numbers can you see my question and give me any idea.
Here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49975361/how-to-calculate-the-sum-for-the-year-angular-4

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for your issue :
make a test in the forEach loop :
I've put 4 dates : 2 under 6 months and 2 older
The result is 80+15  = 95

```js
// After JSON.parse
var todos=[{"due":"28/10/2017","task":"80"},{"due":"06/10/2017","task":"15"},{"due":"06/04/2017","task":"15"},{"due":"06/02/2017","task":"15"}];
var sum = 0;
 var minDate = new Date();
 var month = minDate.getMonth()+1-6; // get month minus 6 months
 var year = minDate.getFullYear(); // get year
 if(month < 1){ // if month is under January then change year
  month+=6;
  year-= 1;
 }
 minDate.setMonth(month); // Replace our min date with our - 6 m
 minDate.setYear(year); // set year in case we have changed

todos.forEach(function(ele){
 var arr = ele.due.split("/"); // split french string date into d,m,y
 if(arr.length==3){
  var dueDate = new Date(arr[2],arr[1],arr[0]); // get the task date
  if(dueDate>minDate){ // if task is not to old then
   sum+=parseInt(ele.task); // sum it

  }
 }
});
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Hi there! Thanks a lot for your reply! Your example works like a charm, but still, when I try to set var todos = localStorage.getItem("todos"), it gives me an error: Uncaught TypeError: todos.forEach is not a function. I think I am not reading the list correctly?

Comment: forEach works on an array, be careful to use it with an array. Didi you JSON.parse your json ?