# How to calculate the sum for the year angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

I have created to sum the costs between each other but now I need to sum all the budget for complete year.
I have tried this but this is not working it is showing me undefined.

Costs is an interface that has a variable created of type date and the variable costs of type number and the id of the actual costs of planned costs it is sending to an array lists actualcostIds.
So how it is possible to calculate all the sum from 1 January to 31 December
Below you will find my code for sum for every each costs and total summed costs.

```
  export interface TotalCosten {
  planned: number;
  actual: number;
}


export function emptyCosts(): Costs {
  return {
    id: '',
    created: new Date(),
    type: 0,
    costs: 0,
    reference: '',
    comment: ''
  };
}



export function getTotalYearCosts(valueItem: ValueItem, allCosts: Map<string, Costs>): TotalCosten {
const totalYearCosts = { planned: 0, actual: 0 };

const Q1 = new Date(2018, 11, 31);
const Q2 = new Date(2018, 0, 1);
  totalYearCosts.actual = valueItem.actualCostIds
.map(costId => allCosts.get(costId, emptyCosts()).costs)
.filter() //Here to make a filter for costs that are in the date range
.reduce((reduction, costs) => reduction + costs, 0);
  return totalYearCosts;
}
export interface ValueItem {
 plannedCostIds: string[];
  actualCostIds: string[];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If i understand your english correctly, you can expand your reduce function to check the date.

> So how it is possible to calculate all the sum depending the date

```
.reduce((reduction, costs) => {
    if (checkDate) {
        return reduction + costs
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}, 0);
```

Comment: I will edit my question to be more understanding, but what I need is to calculate the sum for the months january, february and march when I save a cost it has a budget and the date so to calculate all the sum for this three months. I edited the question

Comment: So you want to filter between .map and .reduce?

Comment: You write some code but can you be more explicit what I have to do, you will save me ?